# The limit of arithmetric mean of a properly divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis

What is the limit of 
$$ S_n := \frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n} $$
for any positive interger $n$, where $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$?

I am trying to show that for any $\beta$ there exist $N$ such that for $n \geq N$ then $S_n > \beta$, but I am struggling with how to determine the $N$.

Comment: What do we know about the variables $$a_i$$?

Comment: We just have the seq {$$a_n$$} properly diverge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n  >k$ we have$$S_n \geq \frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k} n +\frac {a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}+\cdots+a_n} n$$ $$>\frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k} n +\frac {\beta +\beta+\cdots +\beta} n$$ $$=\frac {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k} n +\frac {n-k} n \beta $$ if $k$ is chosen so large that $a_j >\beta$ for $j >k$. Now let $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: Do u mean that the lim Sn >= $\beta$ which is arbitary so it is properly diverge。

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: But is that legal as k depend on beta

Comment: Or it just because the tail of lim equal the lim of whole seq

Comment: It is perfectly legal What I have proved is : $\lim \inf S_n \geq \beta$ for any $\beta $ which implies $S_n \to \infty$.

Comment: Oh , thx a lot I haven‘t noticed that it can be done by lim inf